# Best way to get response from future in Python concurrent futures pool?

Tags: python

I'm submitting a bunch of threads to my thread pool executor like so:

```py
    from concurrent.futures import wait, ALL_COMPLETED
    ...
    futures = []
    pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(8)
    ....
    futures.append(pool.submit(threaded_upload, s3_client, pre_formatted_prefix, bucket))
    wait(futures, timeout=1000, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
```

My question is, before returning from this parent method, I want to aggregate all results from each future (the return value from `threaded_upload` and flatten into a list to return to the caller)

`threaded_upload` is essentially:

```
def threaded_upload(args):
   // do stuff
   return []
```

I threw a wait in there since I want all threads to complete, but how can I go about the final step of merging all results into a single list?

Comment: What is `wait`?

Comment: from concurrent.futures import wait, ALL_COMPLETED

Comment: Your [mre] should always show imports.

Comment: @wwii it has the imports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the result of a future with `future.result()`. Something like this should work for you:

```
from concurrent.futures import wait, ALL_COMPLETED, ThreadPoolExecutor

def threaded_upload(i):
    return [i]

futures = []
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(8)
futures.append(pool.submit(threaded_upload,1))
futures.append(pool.submit(threaded_upload,2))
futures.append(pool.submit(threaded_upload,3))
wait(futures, timeout=1000, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)

merged_list = [v for f in futures for v in f.result()]
print(merged_list)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can I go about the final step of merging all results into a single list?

Don't use concurrent.futures.wait. gather them as they are completed.

```
results = [future.result() for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)]
```